# Generic many-to-many polymorphic association using through?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, many-to-many, polymorphism

Before ask that, I must say that I really searched the web trying to find the answer, but I didn't found any that solved my problem. [Answers like that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895622/activerecordhasmanythroughassociationpolymorphicsourceerror) doesn't solve my problem, because I don't want specify `source_type`, I want a generic thing - you'll understand.

Okay, let's go. I'm using a "many-to-many polymorphic" relationship in my project, but I can't get it to work. Before try to use polymorphic, this was just a "many-to-many" relationship and worked very well, so I want keep the structure, just adding polymorphic.

### Structure:

**Many-to-many:** A `user` and `visitor` has many `subject`, and vice versa. We assume that `user` and `visitor` are **`followers`** and `subject` is **`followed`**.

 **Relationship table:** This objects have a relationship table called "psrelations" (person-subject relations). This table stores the many-to-many relationship.

---

### Models:

**psrelations.rb:**

```
attr_accessible :followed_id, :follower_type, :follower_id
belongs_to :follower, polymorphic: true 
belongs_to :followed, class_name: "Subject"
```

**user.rb:**

```
has_many :psrelations, as: :follower, dependent: :destroy  
has_many :followed_subjects, through: :psrelations, source: :followed
```

**visitor.rb:**

```
has_many :psrelations, as: :follower, dependent: :destroy  
has_many :followed_subjects, through: :psrelations, source: :followed
```

**subject.rb**

```
has_many :psrelations, as: :followed, dependent: :destroy
has_many :followers, through: :psrelations, source: :follower
```

I want that "followers" return all "visitors" and "users", not just one or other, like specifying source_type.

Everything appears to be okay, but when I try to `self.followers.include?(person)` (where person can be either user or visitor), I got:

```
Cannot have a has_many :through association 'Subject#followers' on the polymorphic object 'Follower#follower'.
```

What am I doing wrong?